# Retrieving data from old DVD with open session

Tags: mount, dvd

Given that my current [Easy HDD Recorder by PackardBell](ftp://ftp.packardbell.com/pub/itemnr/6968000300/6968000300_ehdr_ug.pdf) is not working anymore, I have a bunch of recorded DVDs with an open session which I cannot see on the other devices. In particular, it seems that the DVDs are in an open session that has not been closed yet.

```
$ cdrskin dev=/dev/sr1 -minfo 
cdrskin 1.4.8 : limited cdrecord compatibility wrapper for libburn
cdrskin: NOTE : greying out all drives besides given dev='/dev/sr1'
cdrskin: scanning for devices ...
cdrskin: ... scanning for devices done
cdrskin: pseudo-atip on drive 0
cdrskin: status 3 BURN_DISC_APPENDABLE "There is an incomplete disc in the drive"
scsidev: '5,0,0'
Device type    : Removable CD-ROM
Vendor_info    : 'ASUS'
Identifikation : 'SDRW-08D2S-U'
Revision       : 'B901'
Drive id       : '3734508360 406631507228 '
Driver flags   : BURNFREE
Supported modes: TAO SAO
cdrskin: burn_drive_get_write_speed = 11080  (8.0x)
book type:     DVD+R (emulated booktype)
Product Id:    MBIPG101/R04/48
Producer:      Moser Baer India Limited

Mounted media class:      DVD
Mounted media type:       DVD+R
Disk Is not erasable
disk status:              incomplete/appendable
session status:           empty
first track:              1
number of sessions:       1
first track in last sess: 1
last track in last sess:  2
Disk Is unrestricted
Disk type: DVD, HD-DVD or BD

Track  Sess Type   Start Addr End Addr   Size
==============================================
    1     1 Blank  0          15871      15872     
    2     1 Apdbl  15888      2295103    2279216   

Next writable address:              1587392   
Remaining writable size:            707712    

Warning: Incomplete session encountered!
```

This open session is not fixable with wodim:

```
$ wodim -fix   
Device was not specified. Trying to find an appropriate drive...
Detected CD-R drive: /dev/sr1
Device type    : Removable CD-ROM
Version        : 0
Response Format: 2
Capabilities   : 
Vendor_info    : 'ASUS    '
Identification : 'SDRW-08D2S-U    '
Revision       : 'B901'
Device seems to be: Generic mmc2 DVD-R/DVD-RW.
Using generic SCSI-3/mmc DVD-R(W) driver (mmc_mdvd).
Driver flags   : SWABAUDIO BURNFREE 
Supported modes: PACKET SAO
Speed set to 11080 KB/s
Starting to write CD/DVD at speed   8.0 in real unknown mode for single session.
Last chance to quit, starting real write in    0 seconds. Operation starts.
Errno: 5 (Input/output error), reserve track scsi sendcmd: no error
CDB:  53 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
status: 0x2 (CHECK CONDITION)
Sense Bytes: 70 00 05 00 00 00 00 0A 00 00 00 00 24 00 00 00
Sense Key: 0x5 Illegal Request, Segment 0
Sense Code: 0x24 Qual 0x00 (invalid field in cdb) Fru 0x0
Sense flags: Blk 0 (not valid) 
cmd finished after 0.004s timeout 40s
wodim: Cannot open new session
```

Still, it seems that that the initial DVD superblock is missing:

```
$ sudo mount /dev/sr1 /home/famiglia/point   -o session=0
mount: /home/famiglia/point: can't read superblock on /dev/sr1
```

Is there a way to backup the data that is stored in the first written session?

Comment: Captcha does not let me post answers. So as comment:
The first track is unwritten. No chance to read it. For track 2
try "dd if=/dev/sr1 bs=2048 skip=15888 of=dvd_track2.img" or
"sudo mount -o sbsector=15888 /dev/sr1 /home/famiglia/point".
(I you need more diagnosis, mail to me: scdbackup at gmx dot net)

Comment: It seems that there is no superblock in the DVD, and therefore in no way I am able to mount it. Is there a way through which I can manually/automatically create a superblock, so that the dvd_track2.img will be now visible?

Comment: Question is what kind of storage structure is on the DVD.
The complaint about no superblock might mean that there is a filesystem
superblock but it is not recognized by Linux. Normal UDF for DVD should
be recognizable.

Comment: The first sectors in the DVD are not written but, other finalized DVDs that I have, are in the standard DVD video format, and therefore they should be in UDF. I sense that the DVD recorder used to writhe those sectors only when finalizing the DVD. Therefore I'm wondering if it is possible to create a superblock for the dd-ed img file.

Comment: Well, yes. But somebody would have to find out from where the recorder 
took the necessary info to create a chain of up to 5 UDF descriptors
up to the root directory. 
Maybe you find some data recovery tool which can detect the files
in the dd'ed image by their content.
(Google: http://foremost.sourceforge.net/ ... "file carving" ...
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/DataRecovery#Extract_individual_files_from_recovered_image)

Comment: I analysed the data input: simply given, I renamed the file into VOB and, given that the VOB format is just a Video Stream, all the video was retrieved. Therefore, in my case I didn't have to to any preprocessing, but I agree with you that in the general case, with no file names whatsoever, the task would have been more difficult (get each beginning of each video file), if not impossible (e.g., reconstructing the file names).